# Embedding map into Access Database

Tags: software-recommendations, ms-access

I am developing a database for my organisation that could be spatially enabled.

I have to use MS Access 2007 on Windows and am therefore looking for any possibilities to incorporate my Access Database into a mapping tool to embed inside my Access application.

Has anyone successfully created an MS Access project which embeds a mapping window?

I would ideally like to simply geocode my datasets - digitize a point after inputting my data into the DB.

Comment: MapWinGIS Active X component in Access - http://svn.mapwindow.org/svnroot/SampleCode/Access2007_Borehole/ a starting point?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1: http://www.gistimes.com/2012/gis-news/esri-maps-for-microsoft-office/

Answer (score 2):

Use a Web Browser Control on your Access form. Then set the Control Source to (for example, using a text box on my form called txtTotalShops and a field called Address1)

```
="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap&zoom=7&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:orange%7Clabel:" & [txtTotalShops] & "%7C" & Replace([Address1]," ","+") & ",NSW,Australia&key=AAAAAAAA"
```

You can change the zoom, size, markers etc as you wish (Note that the marker properties need `%7C` between them, other properties just an ampersand). Any spaces must be replaced with a plus sign (as in the example for Address1)

You can have up to 15 markers if you are using a human readable address (or unlimited if you use latitude and longitude)

`AAAAA` needs to be replaced with your own Google API key (free for 25,000 map loads per day)

If the whole statement becomes too long for Access, split it into several hidden text boxes on  your form and then concatenate them (`=txtWebAddress1 & txtWebAddress2 & txtWebAddress3`) etc.

Full documentation (and instructions to get your API key) at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers

Answer (score 0):

If you have Access 2010 you can do this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHoy6hsAltc

If not, then perhaps one of these links may help:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.access/jZnlHxayF_g

http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Call-MapQuest-access-t582734.html#Post582734&Zp=

http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/211734-using-google-maps-ms-access

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS_Access/Q_22597280.html

Answer (score -1):

ArcGIS and MapInfo are using the Access File Format (2003) to store their data. you can manage and access your data (not views) from both ArcGIS/MapInfo and MsAccess

Comment: Yes True....I want to actually display a map though with data which is sychnronized from the access db.